# How to avoid repeating Texture Paint edits when image is set to repeat in Shading

Tags: shaders, image, texture-painting

I drew a line in Texture Paint but didn't expect it to repeat like this.

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific what result are you expecting? You risk closing your question. Thank you

Comment: I want to add "chalk lines" to my "soccer field".  I thought it would be best practice to use Texture Paint to do this rather than adding a mesh just to make a line.  I like the fact that I am able to scale down the image to my liking.  The drawback is when I draw a line it repeats wherever the image repeats.  The image itself is only 150px by 150px.

Comment: if you want to keep repeating for grass, You would have to create second UVMap for white lines and mix images together (UVMap that covers whole fiel with big image without repeat).

Comment: That's what I figured but I'm struggling with how to diagram with what I currently have in shading.  I will fiddle with this a little more.

Answer (score 1):

Unwrap object from top view and scale as needed.

[image]

Add new UV Map for line texture and cover whole field.

[image]

In Shader editor add UV Map node for each texture and assign propper map.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want is the *Image Texture Extend* option instead of *Repeat*:

[image]